# EclipseLink multi root JPQL issue

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql, jpa-2.1

I have this query:

```
select d from Baseline b, Deliverable d where b.id = 2 and d member of b.deliverableList
```

and it works perfectly.

But, if I swap roots:

```
select d from Deliverable d, Baseline b where b.id = 2 and d member of b.deliverableList
```

it doesn't work anymore, throwing:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-6015] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Invalid query key [deliverableList] in expression.
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Deliverable jpql="select d from Deliverable d, Baseline b where b.id = 2 and d member of b.deliverableList")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.invalidQueryKeyInExpression(QueryException.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.QueryKeyExpression.validateNode(QueryKeyExpression.java:1011)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.Expression.normalize(Expression.java:3275)
    ...
```

Any idea o.O?

*Please note that using two roots is intentional. I don't want to use `Baseline.getDeliverableList()` because this list holds thousands of elements and i'd like to use pagination.*

Here are the incriminated classes:

```
@Entity
public class Baseline extends HistoricizedEntity
{
    ...

    /** The root. */
    @XmlIDREF
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROOT_ID")
    private Deliverable root;

    /** The deliverable list. */
    @XmlIDREF
    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "BASELINE_DELIVERABLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BASELINE_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DELIVERABLE_ID"))
    private List<Deliverable> deliverableList = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}


@Entity
public abstract class Deliverable extends Unit
{
    ...

    /** The baseline list. */
    @XmlTransient
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "deliverableList")
    protected List<Baseline> baselineList = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I tried this too:

```
public void test4()
{
    EntityManager entityManager = service.getEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Deliverable> query = builder.createQuery(Deliverable.class);

    Root<Baseline> entityRoot = query.from(Baseline.class);
    ListJoin<Baseline, Deliverable> join = entityRoot.join(Baseline_.deliverableList);

    query.select(join);

    query.where
    (
        builder.equal(entityRoot.get(AbstractEntity_.id), 2L)
    );

    Messages.addGlobalInfo("size: {0}", entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList().size());
}
```

same Exception...

however this is a bug of EclipseLink for sure: in Hibernate everything works.

Comment: Looks like a bug, but you can use the relationship in your query and still use pagination.  Try "select d from Baseline b join b.deliverableList d where b.id = 2".  If you are using pagination, you might want to use ordering as well.

Comment: already tried... see update